# c++ allocator crashes the application when not enough memory

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

When allocator fails because of limited memory. The app is crashing. throwing *bad_alloc* or return *nullptr* doesn't stop crash. Anyone have any idea?

```
pointer allocator<T>(size_type count) const
{
    void* buffer = new (count * sizeof(T));
    if (!buffer)         // if buffer == nullptr crashes app
        throw bad_alloc; // doing this crashes app
    /* or alternatively
     * try {
     *     void* buffer = new (count * sizeof(T));
     * } catch (const std::exception& e) {
     *     std::cerr << "failed to allocate " << count << std::endl;
     *     return nullptr;
     * }
     */
}
```

So what to do to gracefully close the app and say not enough memory?

Comment: What sort of crash? What is the backtrace?

Comment: @n.m. It’s pretty unclear what is being asked here but I doubt that question is a duplicate.

Comment: Here is sample http://jrruethe.github.io/blog/2015/11/22/allocators/. Try to allocate UINT64_MAX as `count` in allocator and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

There are various things that are required to not propagate exceptions, which the standard does by specifying that `std::terminate` is called if an exception would otherwise escape.

Without context of the rest of your program, we can't know if it's one of those things, or simply an exception leaving `main`.

A fix to the latter might look like

```
int main()
{
    try 
    {
        // whatever here
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: have an exception catch at main. So that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator throws `bad_alloc` by itself! So use a `try-catch` block:

```
pointer allocator<T>(size_type count) const
{
    try
    {
        void* buffer = new (count * sizeof(T));
    }
    catch (bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        return nullptr; // or do whatever you have to do to recover
    }
}
```

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bad_alloc-in-cpp/) for another example.

Comment: Well, even if I do this, as mentioned "return nullptr" will cause a crash in STL. I want the STL to gracefullly return back with exception "bad_alloc". But it just simply crashes the application.

Comment: catching the bad_alloc isn't the issue. recovering from it is the issue. Because the call is coming from STL, and return nullptr crashes with in STL

Comment: Rather than catching the exception, [call the `std::nothrow` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) of `operator new`.

Comment: @AdnanShaheen The only way of recovering from an out of memory error is to somehow *free* memory, and then rerun the request for allocation. There is no other way.